# The "perfect error": untraceable, unnamed, from neverland

Tags: debugging, azure, feedback, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an experiment running without problems when I run single modules as selected parts.

[image]

The situation is pretty different when I run the entire experiment. In that case it fails, but I cannot know why.

[image]

The experiment returns an error and obviously it doesn't let me deploy the web service, while:

1) I cannot know on **which module** my error is.

2) I don't have an overall description of the error.

3) It could be related to the error here but I cannot know because I don't have any feedback about that. I know that it could be a **bug** Azure is trying to solve but this is not reported anywhere.

I really need to know if that's a bug and if I can do something about that.

Comment: In the second case, the two R Script modules at the bottom of your workspace are not displaying green check marks.  Have you tried viewing the error logs associated with those scripts?

Comment: Already tried: unfortunetely they are both empty.

Comment: Today it seems working fine!! I suspect last week was a little "busy" for the AzureML developers! :)

Comment: Edit: it still is an issue. I hope they will solve because trying to fix the code is really hard when you don't know neither where fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. Please let me know if this happens again